# Erlang: how to set or check TTL in UDP packets?

Tags: networking, erlang, udp, ttl

In Erlang, how can I:

- Set the TTL for sent UDP packets?
- Retrieve the value of the TTL for received UDP packets?

I need to do this to implement [GTSM](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3682.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gen_udp does not currently provide a way to do this.  you would need to modify the inet layer below it to allow for this new functionality.  It would not be difficult to do so, if you look at the other options they allow setting, like multicast_ttl and you can probably implement a gen_udp:send,recv and open that allow for this suppoert.